# How to change font size of first item in Combo Box PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

How do I change the font of the displayed item in the Combo Box.  When the Combo Box displays all the different options, they are the font size I want (20).  However the font size of the item on the actual menu is still small.

```
for dev in devices:
       adding = dev[0]
       item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(adding))
       font = item.font()
       font.setPointSize(20)
       item.setFont(font)
       model.appendRow(item)
comboBox.move(70, 150)
```

Comment: Do you want the font size of the popup and the item selects 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the model only handles the popup, you must use the source of the `QComboBox`:

```
font = comboBox.font()
font.setPointSize(20)
comboBox.setFont(font)
```

Comment: @ekcal8 
If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.