# Font size won't change for selected item

Tags: qt, combobox

I am using a QComboBox in my program with items added on launch. The size of the font for the listed items is correct, but when I select one item, the font size that appears in the main box is different.

I tried this:
[How to change font size of first item in Combo Box PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428377/how-to-change-font-size-of-first-item-in-combo-box-pyqt4)
but I see no results. Modifying the size in Qt Creator's ui editor only changes the size of listed items. At the beginning of my class constructor, I tried this to fix the problem:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

QFont font = ui->OrderNumber_edit->font();
font.setPointSize(15);
ui->OrderNumber_edit->setFont(font);
```

OrderNumber_edit is a pointer to my QComboBox.
Still, I see no changes for the selected item, only for the listed items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that bug.

With the code:

```
ui->comboBox->addItems(QStringList()<<"asdf"<<"qwer");
QFont font = ui->comboBox->font();
font.setPointSize(25);
ui->comboBox->setFont(font);
```

I get the correct result: [[look here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZEiU.png)

Maybe a stylesheet overwrites the font size of your combobox?